# Extending Prototype, Inheritance, and Super

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code

```
const A = class {
    constructor(...args) {
        A.prototype.constructor.apply(this, args);
    }
};

A.prototype.constructor = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

A.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
};


const B = class extends A {};

B.prototype.print = function() {
    super.print();
    console.log('In B!');
};
```

The line of `super.print()` in `B.prototype.print` throws a Syntax error of `'super' keyword unexpected here`. Why?

Why can I not call the class' super like any other language? What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, to call the base class' implementation, you call it explicitly by name, i.e.:

```
B.prototype.print = function() {
    A.prototype.print.call(this);
    console.log('In B!');
};
```

Comment: That's a real shame. Is there a reason there's no `super` support when extending a prototype like this?

Comment: Ultimately that was a design decision when classes were grafted into JavaScript. Of course, it's also worth noting that some other languages have the concept, but use a different keyword (such as `base` in C#)